# Soundness and completeness of systems

Tags: logic, theory, type-systems

First some terminology (borrowed from [here](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/13wi/unit6notes.pdf), page 14):

A **positive** program is a program with an error.

A **negative** program is a program without an error.

So there are four types of programs:

A positive program, analysed as positive -> true positive (TP).

A positive program, analysed as negative -> false negative (FN).

A negative program, analysed as positive -> false positive (FP).

A negative program, analysed as negative -> true negative (TN).

A system is **sound**, if it never accepts a positive program.

A system is **complete**, if it never rejects a  negative program.

So judging by what I wrote above:

```
A complete system accepts FN and TN programs.
A sound system also accepts FN and TN programs.
```

A colleague told me sound systems also accept FP programs. Can someone confirm this and explain why they do?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The book explains it like this:

> Soundness prevents false negatives and completeness prevents false positives.

So in order for the system to be *sound,* it need not prevent false positives, but only false negatives.  To prevent false positives, it must be *complete.*

The book explains it further by using type systems as an example:

> In modern languages, type systems are *sound* (they prevent what they claim to) but not *complete* (they
>   reject programs they need not reject). Soundness is important because it lets language users and language
>   implementers rely on X never happening. Completeness would be nice, but hopefully it is rare in practice
>   that a program is rejected unnecessarily and in those cases, hopefully it is easy for the programmer to modify
>   the program such that it type-checks.
>
> Type systems are not complete because for almost anything you might like to check statically, it is impossible
>   to implement a static checker that given any program in your language (a) always terminates, (b) is sound,
>   and (c) is complete. Since we have to give up one, (c) seems like the best option (programmers do not like
>   compilers that may not terminate).